# Modifying data from an Async task in an entirely different class

Tags: java, android

I would like to know just out of curiosity if there are any convenient ways of pulling data out of an async task created inside a class, and then modifying the data in another class (Without extending classes)

I have a way to do it, but it involves making methods static along with the Async task itself

for example, here I'm just making a string "text" in the Async task

```
public class Main extends Activity{


    //Context ctx;

    static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String,String>{

        static String result;
        private static Context context;


        public MyAsyncTask(Context m)
        {
            this.context = m;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... noArgs) {

            result = "text";

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        public static String getStr()
        {
            return result;
        }


    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
        task.execute();

        final Test t = new Test();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                et.append(t.modifiedString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and in a new class I make a simple String method to modify that data from the async task

```
public class Test{


    public String modifiedString()
    {

//      Main main = null;
//      MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(main.ctx);
//      task.execute();

        String s = (String)Main.MyAsyncTask.getStr();


        return "modified " + s + "\n";
    }

}
```

I'm wondering, is there a way I can do this without having to make the async task static? Perhaps with sharing contexts or something?

by the way I'm not doing this to solve any particular problem, I'm only doing it out of curiosity

Comment: Just to clarify something here, you are trying to access a thread's content from another thread. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: not only access it, But modify it also so I can then bring the result back to the main class

Comment: Well... assuming your thread would be looping inside of doInBackground, you could use onProgressUpdate to store the newly changed string in the AsyncTask instance, you could retrieve it through a getter... that way you would keep things thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a singleton

```
   public class Main extends Activity{

    public static Main instance;
    public static String thestring;

    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String,String>{

        static final String result = "text";
        Context context;


        public MyAsyncTask(Context m)
        {
            this.context = m;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... noArgs) {

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

        public String getStr()
        {
            return result;
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
        task.execute();

        thestring = task.getStr();

        instance = this;

        final Test t = new Test();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                et.append(t.modifiedString());
            }
        });
    }


    public String pulledFromAsyncTask()
    {
        return thestring;
    }


    public static Main getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

and then in the another class

```
public class Test{


    public String modifiedString()
    {
        Main main = Main.getInstance();
        //so with main.something.. you can call the methods you want
        //a good solution is to make a singleton class only for MyAsyncTask setting the
        //functions get/set so you can take the values from other classes


        return "modified " + main.pulledFromAsyncTask() + "\n";

    }

    }
```

Comment: this does seem logical but when I tried it the string is only Null when taken from the async task, I think it's because it can only get the Main instance and not the instance from inside the Async task

Comment: Yes, you should create a function setText(String text) to main so you can call it from your async and then in main create one another function getText that returns the text that you set in setText... Call the setText in your onPostExecute function in MyAsync

Comment: calling the setter in onPostExecute will never work - the getter will always see null, but there are alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Reference to a `Context` in a static way is generally bad idea, it can cause [memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Why don't you simply pass `MyAsyncTask` object to `Test` and then do whatever modifications you want, i.e. non-static fashion?

Comment: Yea, I was actually trying to do this but for some reason it would not let me do that unless everything was static. Perhaps I'm not using contexts properly (quite new to that actually).. I'm not sure how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to testable code static/ singleton is a tough choice.

Depending upon your requirement on the state of data you can however start with an Observer pattern or producer-consumer pattern.

Check out Event bus library for probably an out of the box solution for this use case